# Using content_tag vs writing pure HTML

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm learning Phoenix (and Elixir), and after reading some of the documentation I've noticed a little clash between the way HTML is rendered in templates. And I don't know which method is better to use.

Take for instance the code sample in the phoenix [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/templates.html):

```
<%= for key <- connection_keys(@conn) do %>
    <p><%= key %></p>
<% end %>
```

The code above prints each connection key in a new paragraph. Why would one not do this instead? :

```
<%= for key <- connection_keys(@conn) do
        content_tag :p, key
    end %>
```

Is there any downside to using one over the other? Should I be writing templates in mostly Elixir, or mostly HTML, or a bit of both (what's the industry standard?) ? I also find the second code snippet more readable.

I've realized that with content_tag its possible to write pretty much entire pages in Elixir code without writing any HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix is OSS. Here is the implementation of [`Phoenix.HTML.Tag.content_tag/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#content_tag/2):

→ https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/v2.13.2/lib/phoenix_html/tag.ex#L87

Which is basically the same `html_escape` as in `<%= key %>`.

That said, do whatever you prefer; there is no significant difference, though while in *Phoenix* it probably makes sense to use *Phoenix* helpers.